# redux observable: Why don`t can get all actions in test

Tags: redux, mocha.js, rxjs, sinon, redux-observable

I'm trying to test a 'redux observable epic' but the test fail because not all actions are in store.getActions() the strange is the store.dispatch function runs.

#### Epic and actions

```
export const VERIFY_SESION = 'auth/VERIFY_SESION';
export const SET_POLICIES_ACCEPTED = 'auth/SET_POLICIES_ACCEPTED';
export const AUTHENTICATE = 'auth/AUTHENTICATE';
export function setPoliciesAccepted(wereAccepted: boolean) {
  return {
    wereAccepted,
    type: SET_POLICIES_ACCEPTED,
  };
}

export function verifySesion() {
  return {
    type: VERIFY_SESION,
  };
}

export function authenticate(token) {
  return {
    token,
    type: AUTHENTICATE,
  };
}

export function verifySesionEpic(action$, store) {
  return action$
    .ofType(VERIFY_SESION)
    .switchMap(async () => {
      try {
        store.dispatch(setBlockLoading(true));
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token !== null) {
          store.dispatch(setBlockLoading(false));
          return authenticate(token);
        }
        const policiesWereAccepted = await AsyncStorage.getItem('policiesWereAccepted');
        store.dispatch(setBlockLoading(false));
        return setPoliciesAccepted(policiesWereAccepted);
      } catch (error) {
        return setMessage(error.message);
      }
    });
}
```

#### test

```
describe('actions/auth', () => {
  let store;
  const asyncStorageGetStub = stub(AsyncStorage, 'getItem');

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    asyncStorageGetStub.restore();
  });

  it('Should call authenticate if token', () => {
    const token = 'mitoken';
    asyncStorageGetStub.withArgs('token').returns(Promise.resolve(token));
    store.dispatch(verifySesion());
    expect(store.getActions()).toContain({ type: AUTHENTICATE, token });
  });
});
```

#### Test result

1) "actions/auth Should call epic for verifySesion:
     Error: Expected [ { type: 'auth/VERIFY_SESION' } ] to include { token: 'mitoken', type: 'auth/AUTHENTICATE' }"

#### Note

im sure that the conditional token !== null pass

Comment: Since you're calling the `dispatch` and `expect` syncronous, the first action, that is returned will be the VERIFY, the AUTHENTICATE action will probably we added some time later (depending on how your epic takes to complete)

Answer (score 0):

I was to add a timeout before getAction because the 'AUTHENTICATE' actions is added after.

```
it('Should call authenticate if token', (done) => {
    const token = 'mitoken';
    asyncStorageGetStub.withArgs('token').returns(Promise.resolve(token));
    store.dispatch(verifySesion());
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toContain({ type: AUTHENTICATE, token });
      done();
    }, 1000);
  });
```